# what pixel width I should make for a background cover image

Tags: image, jpeg, retina-display

After reading posts on this site and others, I am uncertain what pixel width I should make for a background cover image. For retina devices it is recommended to create a background image x2 the size if for a non-retina device.

I want to create a background image that will cover the entire screen but this would make a retina device image 2560 x 1760  and non-retina 1920 x 1200 if accommodating large monitors.

Is this too big?
I can't keep the jpeg image file size down to 276KB and that is with the most compression I can apply without destroying the image quality

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is very interesting. To address your comment about what pixel width you should design your background image for. The size of a screen for a laptop, or desktop can vary. So you'll never exactly be able to make a single "universal" image for all backgrounds. Generally diagonal display in inches decides the amount of pixels. My screen is quite large, roughly the biggest size commercially purchased by public. Which is of course 1600 x 900 pixel, 17.3" diagonal display. I wouldn't recommend designing images for any display larger because those displays are custom and more for people who do things like graphic design themselves. Visit http://nodejs.org/logos/ If you scroll down to the computer display, you can see a list of pixel ratios that nodejs designs its logos for. These are very mainstream and popular display sizes. I would recommend you do the same and use those. Hope this answer helped.

**Edit: nodejs builds for quality up to 2560 x 1440. If the size of the files doesn't matter. You should easily be able to build for sizes this large. Hope this helped.**

Comment: yes, I will be making differnt image sizes and usig media quereies what i want to know is if anyone is using 2560 px for retina isplays or not. As a pro-designer and web programmer I am wanting to clarify this. I use a 26" display at 1920 x 1200 but this ofcourse is not a retina display monitor.

Comment: You don't design images specifically for retina display, primarily because 90% of the devices that exist do not have retina display. Also, at a certain point you have to realize, not everyone uses a 26" display.